# SQL Server: how to use IF ELSE or something in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
| id_product | tw_kod | ean  |nazwa     |stan  |cena_detaliczna |
|      1     | 9007   | 9008 | ARR 2016 | 2    |            2490|
|     2      | 9008   | 90085| ION 2018 | NULL |            1450|
```

and this query:

```
select
    tw.id as id_product,
    tw.kod as tw_kod,
    tw.kod as ean,
    tw.nazwa as nazwa,
    sm.stanHandl as stan,
    cn.cena as cena_detaliczna
from 
    [HM].[TW] as tw
join 
    [SSCommon].[STElements] as elem on tw.znacznik = elem.Shortcut
left join 
    [HM].[SM] as sm on tw.id = sm.idtw
left join 
    [HM].[CN] as cn on tw.id = cn.idpm
where
    elem.Shortcut = '66'
    and elem.ElementKindId = '54'
    --and sm.magazyn = 2
    and cn.typceny = 1
order by 
    nazwa
```

Some products were in [HM].[SM] table, some - not. and I use LEFT JOIN for [HM].[SM] to show all products in [HM].[TW], but when I use WHERE clause (sm.magazyn= 2) it doesn't show me products, that's why I commented it. I tried to use IF ELSE in WHERE, but I had not correct result. Thanks

Comment: If you're doing a left join with the [SM] table, the columns from that table will be NULL when the join fails. You need to test for that in where with IS NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add predicate in `FROM` section like this:

```
select
    tw.id as id_product,
    tw.kod as tw_kod,
    tw.kod as ean,
    tw.nazwa as nazwa,
    sm.stanHandl as stan,
    cn.cena as cena_detaliczna
from [HM].[TW] as tw
join [SSCommon].[STElements] as elem on tw.znacznik = elem.Shortcut
left join [HM].[SM] as sm on tw.id = sm.idtw and sm.magazyn = 2
left join [HM].[CN] as cn on tw.id = cn.idpm and cn.typceny = 1
where
    elem.Shortcut = '66'
    and elem.ElementKindId = '54'
    order by nazwa
```

Compassion with `NULL` causes empty resultset